# server side includes: can I compute something inside a variable

Tags: apache, server-side-includes

I'm trying to calculate the current index of my slides depending on the page that is shown.
So far I got this:

```
<!--#set var="page" value="0" -->
<!--#set var="slidesPerPage" value="4" -->

<!--#if expr="$QUERY_STRING = /p=1/" -->
  <!--#set var="page" value="1" -->
<!--#elif expr="$QUERY_STRING = /p=2/"  -->
  <!--#set var="page" value="2" -->
<!--#endif -->
```

Now I want to "calculate" the current index like this:

```
<!--#set var="currentIndex" value="${$page * $slidesPerPage + 1}" -->
```

But this doesn't work.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

after poking around some more and trying things on my own, I found a "solution" that kind of works:

```
<!--#exec cmd="printf $(($page * $slidesPerPage + 1))" -->
```

This just prints the output to page and doesn't store it in a variable, but it's enough for me right now.

If someone has a better/nicer solution, please let me know.